# can't limit search to only pages

Tags: search

I'm trying to limit a search to only pages, but it isn't working properly. When I include this hidden field in the search form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="page" />
```

The results include posts, pages, and custom post types. If I change the above to search only posts, it works properly, and only posts are displayed. Anyone have any ideas why it won't properly restrict my post to only display pages?

I need to restrict the results for this search form only, so modifying the search query results in the search results template or in functions.php won't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick test on a default install with TwentyEleven confirms this, and I'm not sure why this is the case, however there is a way you can do this via your `functions.php`.

add a hidden field to the form with your own query var:

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_type" value="page" />
```

or:

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_type" value="post,page" />
```

add the new query var to WP's recognized query vars:

```
function wpse50828_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'my_type';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse50828_query_vars' );
```

add your code to set the post type when that query var is set:

```
function wpse50828_search( $query ){
    if( get_query_var('my_type') )
        $query->set('post_type', explode( ',', get_query_var('my_type') ));

    return $query;
}
add_action( 'parse_query','wpse50828_search' );
```

Comment: brilliant. Thanks. Anyway to have it return both posts and pages?

Comment: @JohnChandler see edited code above